# Evaluating the integral, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln\left(1 - e^{-x}\right) \,\mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I recently got stuck on evaluating the following integral. I do not know an effective substitution to use. Could you please help me evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln\left(1 - e^{-x}\right) \,\mathrm dx $$

Comment: Use braces for longer exponents, so `e^{-x}`, not `e^-x`

Comment: I've edited the LaTeX so that $e^{-x}$ appears correctly (and also merged your accounts, Jack).

Comment: The integrand is undefined, since $e^{-x}-1$ is negative. Do you mean $\ln|e^{-x}-1|$?

Comment: Yes, I dropped a negative sign from in front of the integrand and have edited the question.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One route to evaluating the integral is
$$-\int_0^\infty \ln(1-e^{-x})dx=\int_0^\infty\left(e^{-x}+\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}+\frac{e^{-3x}}{3}+\cdots\right)dx $$
$$=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-2x}dx+\frac{1}{3}\int_0^\infty e^{-3x}dx+\cdots$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdots $$
$$=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

I don't know if a straightforward substitution could get you the answer, what with this being the [Riemann zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) and all, but you can see the integrals on the linked page and try your own hand at finding one. (Or someone else can try their hand.)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! Another post observed that zeta(2) is the area under the curve e^-x + e^-y = 1 and now I guess I have more to think about. haha

Comment: @Jack: Was it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2/8418#8418, by any chance?

Comment: Yes it was. - I see now, that my question was answered in that thread. @Hans: I find your comment there very intriguing.

Answer (score 16):

Integrating by parts it is easily reducible to [integral representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) of $\Gamma(s) \zeta(s)$ at $s=2$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
   \int_0^\infty \log\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-x}\right) \, \mathrm{d} x &=& \lim  x \log\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-x}\right) \vert_{0^+}^\infty  - \int_0^\infty x \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x}} \mathrm{d} x \\ &=& - \int_0^\infty x \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x}} \mathrm{d} x = -\Gamma(2) \zeta(2).
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Answer (score 10):

Not as snazzy as anon's answer, but:

If you start with the usual series for the logarithm:

$$-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k+1}$$

the [dilogarithm function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12.i) $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$ is

$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)=-\int_0^x\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\mathrm dt=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^2}$$

From the series representation, we find that $\mathrm{Li}_2(1)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$; it remains to manipulate the integral

$$-\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\mathrm dt=\int_1^0\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\mathrm dt$$

Letting $t=\exp(-u),\quad \mathrm dt=-\exp(-u)\mathrm du$, we get

$$-\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1-\exp(-u))}{\exp(-u)}\exp(-u)\mathrm du$$

which is the negative of the OP's integral.

Answer (score 6):

A related family of integrals is the following. Consider the [polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), $\mathsf{Li}_{s}(x) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{x^{k}}{k^{s}}$. By Parseval's Theorem,
$$
\int_{0}^{1} | \mathsf{Li}_{s}(e^{2 \pi i x})|^{2} dx =  \sum_{k \geq 1} \left| \frac{e^{2 \pi i k x}}{k^{s}} \right|^{2} = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k^{2s}} = \zeta(2s).
$$
Since $\mathsf{Li}_{1}(x) = - \ln (1 - x)$, we have
$$
\int_{0}^{1} | \ln (1 - e^{2\pi i x})|^{2} dx  = \zeta(2).
$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider following parametric integral$$I(\alpha )=\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln\left(1 - \alpha e^{-x}\right) \,\mathrm dx$$

We have $I(0)=0$ and $I(1)$ will yield required integral

$$I'(\alpha )=-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{1-\alpha  e^{-x}} \,\mathrm dx=
\left[\frac{x}{\alpha }-\frac{\ln \left(e^x-\alpha \right)}{\alpha }\right]_0^{\infty}=\frac{\ln(1-\alpha )}{\alpha }$$

$$I(\alpha )=-\operatorname{Li}_2(\alpha )+c$$

$$I(0)=0\implies I(\alpha )=-\operatorname{Li}_2(\alpha )$$

$$I(1)=-\operatorname{Li}_2(1)=-\zeta(2)=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

> $$\large\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln\left(1 - e^{-x}\right) \,\mathrm dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this answer is too late. Let $t=1-e^{-x}$. Then
$$ \int_0^\infty\ln(1-e^{-x})dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln t}{1-t}dt=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}. $$

Answer (score 2):

break $\ln(1-e^{-x})$ like $\ln(1-t) = y-y^2/2-y^3/3- \cdots$ where $y = e^{-x}$
then break at the addition/subtraction point in integration.
then evaluate.