# Evaluation of the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1 - x)}{1 + x}dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration

How can I evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1 - x)}{1 + x}dx$$ 
I tried manipulating the known integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1 - x)}{x}dx = -\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
but couldn't do anything with it.

Comment: Wolfram alpha mentions [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$. May be relevant: $\operatorname{Li}_1(x) = - \ln(1-x)$.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use double integration:

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\log \left( {1 - x} \right)}}{{1 + x}}dx}  = \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^{ - x} {\frac{{du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {1 + u} \right)\left( {1 + x} \right)}}} } $$

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^x {\frac{{dm \cdot dx}}{{\left( {m - 1} \right)\left( {1 + x} \right)}}} } $$

Now make

$$m = ux $$

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{x \cdot du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)\left( {1 + x} \right)}}} }  = \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)}}} }  - \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)\left( {1 + x} \right)}}} } $$

We have that (partial fraction decomposition)

$$\frac{1}{ \left( ux - 1 \right)\left( x + 1 \right) } = \frac{u}{ \left( u + 1 \right)\left( ux - 1 \right) } - \frac{1}{ \left( x + 1 \right)\left( u + 1 \right) }$$

So we get

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)}}} }  - \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{u \cdot du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)\left( {u + 1} \right)}}} }  + \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {x + 1} \right)\left( {u + 1} \right)}}} } $$

Now:

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)}}} }  = \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\log \left( {1 - u} \right)}}{u}} du =  - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{6}$$

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{du\cdot dx}}{{\left( {x + 1} \right)\left( {u + 1} \right)}}} }  = {\log ^2}2$$

For our last one,note it is the integral we're looking for

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{u\cdot du\cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)\left( {u + 1} \right)}}} \mathop  = \limits^{ux = m} } \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^u {\frac{{dm\cdot du}}{{\left( {m - 1} \right)\left( {u + 1} \right)}}} } \mathop  = \limits^{m =  - x} \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^{ - u} {\frac{{dx\cdot du}}{{\left( {x + 1} \right)\left( {u + 1} \right)}}} }  = \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\log \left( {1 - u} \right)}}{{ {u + 1} }}} du$$

We get

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\log \left( {1 - u} \right)}}{{ {u + 1} }}} du = {\log ^2}2 - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{6} - \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\log \left( {1 - u} \right)}}{{ {u + 1} }}} du$$

or

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\log \left( {1 - u} \right)}}{{{u + 1} }}} du = \frac{{{{\log }^2}2}}{2} - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{12}}$$

as desired.

Comment: @Martin In a similar fashion, you can try and prove that

$$\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\log \left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}}{{x + 1}}dx = \frac{3}{4}{{\log }^2}2 - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{48}}} $$

Comment: I looked at it briefly and it seems right to me. Well done!

Comment: +1. The step which replaces the logarithm by an integral to reach a double integral to be further massaged is worth remembering.

Comment: This is wonderful derivation Peter. Very clever, clear and accessible to everyone. Thank you very much.

Comment: Everything looks correct (+1). However, when you had
$$
\color{red}{\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{x \cdot du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)\left( {1 + x} \right)}}} }}
=\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)}}} }  - \color{red}{\int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{u \cdot du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {ux - 1} \right)\left( {u + 1} \right)}}} }}  + \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{du \cdot dx}}{{\left( {x + 1} \right)\left( {u + 1} \right)}}} }
$$
the red integrals are equal and you could simply add and divide by $2$.

Comment: @robjohn That's right. I kind of did that but first I rolled it back.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for that! Glad to help.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the integral you want to use, and the [Dilogarithm](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#i) function as mentioned in the comments.

Below we give a complete proof, including a derivation of the value of the integral you wanted to use.

The Dilogarithm function is defined as

$$\text{Li}_2(z) = -\int_{0}^{z} \frac{\log (1-x)}{x} \text{dx} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}, \quad |z| \le 1$$

The integral which you want to use is $\displaystyle -\text{Li}_2(1)$.

Note that $\displaystyle \text{Li}_2(1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. (For multiple proofs of that, see here: [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2))

In your integral(whose value you want), make the substitution $\displaystyle x = 2t -1$ and we get

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} \frac{\log (2(1-t))}{t} \text{dt} = \log^2 2 + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} \frac{\log (1-t)}{t} \text{dt} = \log^2 2 + \text{Li}_2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) - \text{Li}_2(1) $$

Now the Dilogarithm function also satisfies the identity

$$\text{Li}_2(x) + \text{Li}_2(1-x)  = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log x \log (1-x), 0 \lt x \lt 1$$

This identity can easily be proven by just differentiating and using the value of $\displaystyle \text{Li}_2(1)$:

$$\text{Li}_2'(x) - \text{Li}_2'(1-x) = -\frac{\log (1-x)}{x} + \frac{\log x}{1-x} = (-\log x \log (1-x))'$$

and so 
$$\text{Li}_2(x) + \text{Li}_2(1-x)  = C -\log x \log (1-x), 0 \lt x \lt 1$$

Taking limits as $\displaystyle x \to 1$ gives us $\displaystyle C = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Thus

$$\text{Li}_2(x) + \text{Li}_2(1-x)  = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log x \log (1-x), 0 \lt x \lt 1$$

Setting $\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{2}$ gives us the value of $\displaystyle \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{12} - \frac{\log^2 2}{2}$

Thus your integral is

$$\log^2 2 + \text{Li}_2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) - \text{Li}_2(1) = \frac{\log^2 2}{2} - \frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: Also see J.M's answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60492/1102

Comment: Thank you Aryabhata. I never saw this Dilogarithm function before, but it looks as very useful one.

Comment: @Martin: You are welcome. Thank you for the nice problem.

Comment: @Aryabhata Nice reflection formula! Check my answer, tell me what you think.

Comment: @PeterT.off: Thanks! Your answer seems very interesting. I will go through it sometime soon.

Comment: @Aryabhata Ok, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x = -\,{\pi^{2} \over 6}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 2 - x}\,\dd x
> =\int_{0}^{1/2}{\ln\pars{2x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> \overbrace{\left.\vphantom{\Huge a}-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{2x}\right\vert_{0}^{1/2}}
> ^{\ds{=\ 0}}\ +\
> \int_{0}^{1/2}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,{1 \over x}\,\dd x
> =\color{#c00000}{-\int_{0}^{1/2}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm Li_{s}}\pars{z}}$ is the [PolyLogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). We already used $\ds{{\rm Li_{1}}\pars{z} = -\ln\pars{1 - z}}$.

With the identity ( see the above mentioned link )
$\ds{{\rm Li_{s + 1}}\pars{z} = \int_{0}^{z}{{\rm Li_{s}}\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t}$
we'll have:
$$
\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}
=\color{#c00000}{-{\rm Li_{2}}\pars{\half}}
$$

Also, ( see the above mentioned link )
$\ds{{\rm Li_{2}}\pars{\half} = {\pi^{2} \over 12} - \half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}}$ which is a consequence of

*Euler Reflection Formula*
$\ds{{\rm Li_{2}}\pars{x} + {\rm Li_{2}}\pars{1 - x}
     ={\pi^{2} \over 6} -\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}}$.

> $$
> \color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
> =\half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2} - {\pi^{2} \over 12}}
> $$

Answer (score 2):

Maple says it's $${(\log2)^2\over2}-{\pi^2\over12}$$ To get there, I think you will have to understand how the known integral you cite was established, and then use the same ideas to do yours (perhaps after first following Emile's calculations).

Comment: Besides Maple, how did you arrive to this answer ?.

Comment: @Felix, Maple is the only way I arrived at an answer. But a couple of other detailed answers have been posted. Are you happy with them?

Answer (score 2):

Following is an elementary proof.

I assume only that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}dx\\
&\overset{y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)}{1+y}dy\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+y}\right)}{1+y}dy+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt\\
&\overset{u=\frac{1-y}{1+y}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1+u\right)}{1+u}du+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2 2+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx-\int_0^1 \frac{2t\ln t}{1-t^2}dt\\
&\overset{w=t^2}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln w}{1-w}dw\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{12}\pi^2
\end{align}
Therefore,

$\boxed{\displaystyle J=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2 2-\frac{1}{12}\pi^2}$

Comment: Very nice (+1). I like the idea of using the common subbing twice.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this is not a complete solution, but may serve as a starter*

First let $2u=x+1$ and thus $2du=dx$. Then we get:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}dx=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln(2-2u)}{2u}2du$$
$$=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln(2(1-u))}{u}du=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln2+\ln(1-u)}{u}du$$
$$=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln2}{u}du+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u}du$$

Comment: Take care of limits of integration!

Comment: Ok, I'll edit to include them too.

Comment: @Emile Okada: Thank you. Now we have to calculate the second integral, but with new limit of integration.

Comment: @Martin No problem! To calculate the second integral look at Aryabhata answer. He gives a thorough explanation of how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

With subbing $1-x=y$ we have

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^a(1-x)}{1+x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^a(y)}{2-y}dy$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^1 y^{n-1}\ln^a(y)dy$$

$$=(-1)^aa!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^nn^{a+1}}=(-1)^aa!\text{Li}_{a+1}\left(\frac12\right)$$

**Some cases:**

By using $\text{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)=\frac12\zeta(2)-\frac12\ln^2(2)$ and $\text{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)=\frac78\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln(2)\zeta(2)+\frac16\ln^3(2)$  we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}\ dx=-\text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac12\right)=-\frac12\zeta(2)+\frac12\ln^2(2)\label{ln(1-x)/(1+x)}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x}\ dx=2\text{Li}_{3}\left(\frac12\right)=\frac74\zeta(3)-\ln(2)\zeta(2)+\frac13\ln^3(2)\label{ln^2(1-x)/(1+x)}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1+x}\ dx=-6\text{Li}_{4}\left(\frac12\right)\label{ln^3(1-x)/(1+x)}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{1+x}\ dx=24\text{Li}_{5}\left(\frac12\right)\label{ln^4(1-x)/(1+x)}
\end{align}