# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{\log x \log \left(1-x^4 \right)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am trying to prove that

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(x\right)
\log\left(\,{1 - x^{4}}\,\right)}{1 + x^{2}}
\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi^{3}}{16} - 3\mathrm{G}\log\left(2\right)
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $\mathrm{G}$ is [Catalan's Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

I was able to express it in terms of Euler Sums but it does not seem to be of any use.

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(x\right)
\log\left(\,{1 - x^{4}}\,\right)}{1 + x^{2}}
\,\mathrm{d}x
\\[3mm] = &\
\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\frac{\psi_{1}\left(1/4 + n\right) -
\psi_{1}\left(3/4 + n\right)}{n} \tag{2}
\end{align}

Here $\psi_{n}\left(z\right)$ denotes the [polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html).

Can you help me solve this problem $?$.

Comment: Its value equals $0.033195385237175505243536463953369601991099944635828. $

Comment: Taking $u=\log(1+x^2)$, I get $\tfrac 12 \sqrt {e^u-1}du={dx\over 1+x^2}$, and then the original has broken apart to $\int_0^1{\log x(\log (1-x)+\log (1+x))\over 1+x^2}dx +\int\tfrac 12 \sqrt{e^u-1}\log\sqrt{e^u-1}du$...  Hmm, that doesn't really help much though...

Comment: That sum can also be expressed as $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{(4n+1)^{2}} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{(4n+3)^{2}}$$

Comment: I'm surprised Ron hasn't jumped on this one yet.

Comment: I find that Mathematica can do this integral with a bit of prodding. Are you looking for just any way of establishing this, or do you also want it to be human-readable?

Comment: @Kirill: I think it would be great if the solution is human friendly.

Comment: The indefinite integral is the imaginary part of this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+Log%5Bx%5DLog%5B1-x%5E4%5D%2F(x-I)

Comment: Can I buy a vowel please?  Where did this integral come from?

Comment: @johnmangual: I saw it posted on AoPS forum a long time ago.

Comment: I don't know if this will be of any use, but I find the following interesting: $$\frac{\pi}{4} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2 k+1}$$ $$\frac{\pi^2}{12} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2} $$ $$\log{2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} $$ $$G = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^2}$$

Comment: @BennettGardiner: rest assured that I have spent some not insignificant time on this.  The best I could muster was the above observation.  I gained nothing from my usual arsenal.

Comment: Me too, I think a few people have.

Comment: The reflection formula of $\psi_1$ may help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I tried substitutions and the differentiation w.r.t a paramater trick like the other posters. Another partial result, or a trail of breadcrumbs to follow, is the following. We try a series expansion,
$$
\frac{\log\left(1-x^4\right)}{1+x^2} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{4k}\left(x^{2} -1\right)H_k,
$$
where $H_k$ are the Harmonic numbers. Then 
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log x \log \left(1-x^4 \right)}{1+x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x &=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\, H_k\int_0^1 x^{4k}\left(x^{2} -1\right)\log x \ \mathrm{d}x  \\
&=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \, \frac{H_k}{(4k+1)^2}-\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \, \frac{H_k}{(4k+3)^2}.
\end{align}
These sums look very similar to the ones evaluated in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/316749/78722) post, in which they are transformed into alternating sums. Using the same techniques, or perhaps working back from the answers, we can hopefully show that
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \, \frac{H_k}{(4k+1)^2} = -G\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\log 8}{2} \right) +\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3) +\frac{\pi^3}{32} - \frac{\pi^2}{16}\log 8,
$$
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \, \frac{H_k}{(4k+3)^2} = -G\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\log 8}{2} \right) +\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3) -\frac{\pi^3}{32} - \frac{\pi^2}{16}\log 8,
$$
Subtracting the second from the first gives us 
$$
\frac{\pi^3}{16}-G\log 8.
$$

Comment: $$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{H_k}{(k+a)^2} = (\gamma+\psi(a))\psi_1(a)-{\textstyle\frac12}\psi_2(a).$$

Comment: @Bennet Gardiner: Thank you! I just need to find out a way to evaluate those Euler Sums.

Comment: Hey @Kirill - what's the derivation for that? Are you saying we could just let $a=1/4$ and $a=3/4$?

Comment: I used computer algebra.

Comment: I posted a derivation of that formula in this thread.

Answer (score 16):

The following is a proof of the formula $$S= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{k}}{ (k+a)^{2}}= \left(\gamma + \psi(a) \right) \psi_{1}(a) - \frac{\psi_{2}(a)}{2} \, , \quad a >0.$$

This formula is mentioned in a comment under Bennett Gardiner's answer.

(For $a=0$, the right side of the equation should be interpreted as a limit).

$$ \begin{align}  S &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{k}}{(k+a)^{2}} \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+a)^{2}} \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n}  \\& = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{(k+a)^2} \\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi_{1}(a+n)}{n}  \\ &= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{a+n-1} \ln x}{1-x} \, dx \tag{1} \\ &= - \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{x^{a-1} \ln x}{1-x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n} \, dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{a-1} \ln x \ln(1-x)}{1-x} \, dx \\ &= \lim_{b \to 0^{+}} \frac{\partial }{\partial a \, \partial b} B(a,b) \\ &= \small  \lim_{b \to 0^{+}} \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)} \left( \psi(a) \psi(b) - \psi(a)\psi(a+b) - \psi(b) \psi(a+b) + \psi^{2}(a+b) - \psi_{1}(a+b) \right) \tag{2} \\ &=  \lim_{b \to 0^{+}} \frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(a+b)} \left( \frac{1}{b} - \gamma + \mathcal{O}(b) \right)\left( \left( \gamma \psi_{1}(a) + \psi(a) \psi_{1} (a)  - \frac{\psi_{2}(a)}{2} \right)b + \mathcal{O}(b^{2}) \right) \\ &= \left(\gamma + \psi(a) \right) \psi_{1}(a) -  \frac{\psi_{2}(a)}{2} \end{align}$$

---

$(1)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function#Calculation

$(2)$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html (26)

Comment: This is the key step in the proof, really.

Comment: $+1$. That's wonderful.

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial solution.

Let us put, for $0\leq t\leq 1$,

$$F(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{\log x \log(1-tx^4)}{1+x^2} dx$$

Then

$$F'(t) = -\int_0^1 \frac{x^4\log x}{(1+x^2)(1-tx^4)} dx =  -\int_0^1 \frac{x^4\log x}{1+x^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^nx^{4n} dx$$

$$=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{n} C_{4(n+1)}$$

where $$C_m = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{m}\log x}{1+x^2} dx.$$

One has $C_0 = -G$. Multiplying both sides of the identity
$$x^m = \frac{x^m}{1+x^2} + \frac{x^{m+2}}{1+x^2}$$
by $\log x$ and integrating from $0$ to $1$, one finds the recurrence formula

$$C_m + C_{m+2} = \frac{-1}{(1+m)^2}$$

and therefore

$$C_{m+4} - C_m = \frac{-1}{(3+m)^2} + \frac{1}{(1+m)^2}.$$

Therefore,

$$C_0 = -G$$
$$C_4 = -G +1 - \frac{1}{3^2}$$
$$C_8 = -G + 1 - \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{5^2} - \frac{1}{7^2}.$$

and so on. (Remark that $C_{4n} \to 0$ by definition of $G$.) Now, remark that $F(0) = 0$, so your integral is

$$F(1) = \int_0^1 F'(t) dt = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{C_{4(n+1)}}{n+1} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{C_{4n}}{n}.$$

Now, it should be a matter of partial summation to transform the sum $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{C_{4n}}{n}$ into $\pi^3/16 -3G\log 2$ (in a manner similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/304998/12507)), but I don't see it right away. I'll think about it a bit more later.

Comment: This appears to be equivalent to the equation (2) in the question, by the definition of the trigamma function $\psi_1$.

Comment: Dear @Kirill, how so?

Comment: The solution to your recurrence for $C_{4n}$ is $$C_{4n}=\frac{\psi_1(\frac34+k)-\psi_1(\frac14+k)}{16}, $$ so evaluating the sum $\sum\frac{C_{4n}}{n}$ is still not not trivial.

Comment: Dear @Kirill, what you write is not obvious to me. Perhaps I am overlooking something? (What is $k$?) I think that a partial summation method can definitely take care of this sum. See for example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/304998/12507), which is similar.

Comment: Oops, $k$ is meant to be $n$---error in trasncription. All I meant was that the final expression you derived was already posted in the answer, so it's not really fair to say "it should be a matter of partial summation to transform the sum".

Comment: Dear @Kirill I understand your claim, but your formula for $C_{4n}$ is not obvious to me. That's what I am saying. I am not disputing your formula. In any case, I **do** believe that it should be a matter of partial summation. Certainly it is fair for me to speak my mind on the matter. I did not claim that it should be trivial. Regards,

Comment: It's a consequence of [(19) here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html), and the definition $\psi_1=\frac{d\psi}{dz}$.

Answer (score 5):

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \log \left(1-x^4 \right)}{1+x^2}dx$$

Let,

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle A&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\arctan x\ln x}{1+x^2}dx\\
\displaystyle B&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x \ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx\\
\displaystyle C&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\arctan x\ln x}{1+x}dx\\
\end{align*}

From [Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)dx=\frac{G\ln 2}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896955/evaluating-int-0-pi-4-ln-tan-x-ln-cos-x-sin-xdx-fracg-ln-22) ,

it follows that,

$$\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=A-\dfrac{1}{2}B-C-2G\ln 2+\beta(3)$$

and,

$$(1)\boxed{A=\dfrac{1}{64}\pi^3-B-G\ln 2}$$

with,

$$\displaystyle \beta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}$$

Thus,

$$(2)\boxed{\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\dfrac{\pi^3}{64}-\dfrac{3}{2}B-C-3G\ln 2+\beta(3)}$$

$G$, being the Catalan constant,

From [Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln(\tan x)\ln(\cos x-\sin x)dx=\frac{G\ln 2}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896955/evaluating-int-0-pi-4-ln-tan-x-ln-cos-x-sin-xdx-fracg-ln-22) ,

it follows that,

$$\displaystyle\int_0^{1}\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx=A+\dfrac{1}{2}B+\beta(3)+\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan x }{1-x}dx$$

and,

$$\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\arctan x}{1-x}dx=B-C+2G\ln 2-\dfrac{1}{16}\pi^3$$

Thus, using (1),

$$(3)\boxed{\displaystyle\int_0^{1}\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}B-C+G\ln 2-\dfrac{3\pi^3}{64}+\beta(3)}$$

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \log \left(1-x^4 \right)}{1+x^2}dx&=\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx+\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx+\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=B+\dfrac{\pi^3}{64}-\dfrac{3}{2}B-C-3G\ln 2+\beta(3)+\dfrac{1}{2}B-C+G\ln 2-\dfrac{3\pi^3}{64}+\beta(3)\\
&=2\beta(3)-\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}-2G\ln 2-2C
\end{align}

$C$ have been already evaluated (see [Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x \log x}{1+x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842284/evaluating-int-01-frac-arctan-x-log-x1xdx/1842492#1842492) )

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\displaystyle C=\dfrac{G\ln 2}{2}-\dfrac{\pi^3}{64}}
\end{equation}

and, knowing that,

\begin{equation}
 \beta(3)=\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}
\end{equation}

it follows that,

$$\boxed{I=\dfrac{\pi^3}{16}-3G\ln 2}$$

Answer (score 4):

We may use a simple strategy for a similar type of integral that appears in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, page $80$, integral $J_1$.

So, we have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log(1-x^4)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{ (1-x^2)\log (x)\log(1-x^4)}{1-x^4} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{16}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x)\log (1-x) }{x^{3/4}(1-x) }\textrm{d}x}_{\displaystyle \text{Beta function}}-\frac{1}{16}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x)\log (1-x) }{x^{1/4}(1-x)} \textrm{d}x}_{\displaystyle \text{Beta function}}=\frac{\pi^3}{16}-3\log(2)G.$$

Answer (score 3):

Presented below is a self-contained evaluation. With
$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt =-G$

\begin{align*}
I & = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \ln (1-x^4 )}{1+x^2}dx \\
& = \int_0^1 \ln (1-x^4 ) d\left(\int_1^x \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt \right) \overset{IBP}=\int_0^1 \frac{ 4x^3}{1-x^4} \underset{t=xs }{\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt +G \right) } dx \\
& =4\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 \frac{x^4 \ln x+x^4\ln s }{(1-x^4 )(1+x^2s^2)}ds +\frac{Gx^3}{1-x^4} \right) dx\\
& =4\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^4\ln x}{(1-x^4)(1+x^2s^2)}dsdx -4 \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln s}{1+x^2s^2}dx ds \\
& \>\>\>\>\>+ 4 \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln s }{(1-x^4 )(1+x^2s^2)}ds +\frac{Gx ^3}{1-x^4} \right) dx\\
\end{align*}
Integrate the 2nd integral
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln s}{1+x^2s^2}dx ds =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln s\tan^{-1}s}sds
\overset{IBP}=-\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2s}{1+s^2}ds=-\frac{\pi^3}{32}
\end{align*}

and apply the decomposition below in the 3rd integral

$$\frac{1 }{(1-x^4 )(1+x^2s^2)}
= \frac{-s^4}{(1-s^4)(1+x^2s^2)} +\frac1{2(1-s^2)(1+x^2)}+ \frac1{2(1+s^2)(1-x^2)}
$$
Then, the 1st integral cancels and
\begin{align*}
I =& -4\left(-\frac{\pi^3}{32}\right)
+2\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln s }{(1-s^2 )(1+x^2)}dx ds \\
&\>\>\> + 2\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 \frac{\ln s }{(1+s^2 )(1-x^2)}ds  +\frac{2Gx ^3}{1-x^4}\right) dx\\
= & \frac{\pi^3}8+ 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln s ds }{1-s^2}\int_0^1\frac{dx }{1+x^2}
 -2G \int_0^1 \left( \frac{1}{1-x^2} -\frac{2x^3}{1-x^4}\right) dx\\
 = & \frac{\pi^3}8+ 2\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\right) \frac\pi4
 -2G \int_0^1 \left( \frac{x}{1+x^2} +\frac{1}{1+x}\right) dx\\
 = & \frac{\pi^3}{16}
 -3G\ln2\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Quanto you should collect your solutions into a book ... they are unique!

Comment: @AliShadhar - nice suggestion; just might as well at some point

Comment: It would be great if you make use of your tricks to find generalizations

Answer (score 0):

I have several pieces of this, but can't quite put them together.  Perhaps someone else can pick up from here.

$\int_0^1 \frac{logxlog(1-x^4)}{(1+x^2)}dx$

We are going to let $u = (1-x^4)$ giving du = $-4x^3dx$.

Rewriting the first integral we have

$\int_0^1 \frac{-4x^3logxlog(1-x^4)}{-4x^3(1+x^2)}dx$ =

$\int_0^1 \frac{log(1-u)^{1/4}log(u)}{-4(1-u)^{3/4}(1+u^{1/2})}du$ =

(-1/16)$\int_0^1 \frac{log(1-u)log(u)}{(1-u)^{3/4}(1+(1-u)^{1/2})}du$

Let v = 1-u so dv = -du  which gets us to

(1/16)$\int_0^1 \frac{log(v)log2(v^{1/2}(v^{-1/2}-v^{1/2})/2}{(v)(v^{-1/4}+v^{1/4})}dv \hspace{50px}$   The fact that the 1/16 shows up is encouraging.

Now let w = log v so that v = $e^w$  and dw = (1/v)dv.  So now we have

(1/16)$\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{w[ log 2 + w/2 + log(-sinh(w))}{2(cosh(v/2)}dw$

Having gotten this far the next step is the Catalan constant which can be defined as $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} = 1/1^2 - 1/3^2 + 1/5^2 ... $

The log (-sinh(w)) can be expanded in a Taylor's series, with the idea of integrating term by term, and there is some reason to hope that it will produce something helpful. The source of this hope is

[Evaluating $\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \log\left( \cos x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199094/evaluating-a-definite-integral-involving-log-cos-x)

What I can't see right now is what would happen with all the other stuff in the integral, but one could hope things might work out.