# Integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln\left(\sqrt{\sin^3{x}}+\sqrt{\cos^3{x}}\right)dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Yesterday my friend emailed me a math question, which perplexed me greatly when I first read it. I've been working on it, but I can't solve it.

Show that

> $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln\left(\sqrt{\sin^3{x}}+\sqrt{\cos^3{x}}\right)dx=\dfrac{G}{12}-\dfrac{5\pi}{16}\ln{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}\ln{(2-\sqrt{2})}-\dfrac{\pi}{8}\ln{(2+\sqrt{2})}-\dfrac{\pi}{3}\ln{(\sqrt{3}-1)}+\dfrac{\pi}{3}\ln{(1+\sqrt{3})}$$

where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Have you broken down the $a^3+b^3$ form and separated based on properties of $\ln$?

Comment: I have try it,But not usefull.Thank you

Comment: Note that the answer can be simplified to 
$$
\dfrac{G}{12}-\dfrac{5\pi}{16}\ln{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}\ln{(3-2\sqrt{2})}+\dfrac{\pi}{3}\ln{(2+\sqrt{3})}$$

Comment: I was able to reduce the original integral to $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+z^3)}{1+z^4}dz$ but that's the furthest I can go through.

Comment: After AstroSharp reduction, we can probably use the method shown here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426325/evaluate-int-01-frac-log-left-1x2-sqrt3-right1xdx?rq=1

Comment: I'm afraid those integrals aren't numerically equivalent @AstroSharp.

Comment: where did this integral come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can attempt this using some results of questions that have been asked lately. I will lay out some partial results that hopefully someone else can use.
First, note that 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln{(\sqrt{\sin^3{x}}+\sqrt{\cos^3{x}})}\ \mathrm{d}x & = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln{(\tan^{3/2}(x)+1)}\ \mathrm{d}x + \frac{3}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln{\cos(x)}\ \mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
The second integral can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/199138/78722), giving us that 
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln{\cos(x)}\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{4} (2G-\pi\log 2),
$$
where $G$ is Catalan's constant. So you can see we are at least recovering some pieces.

For the first integral, we try a substitution $z = \tan^{1/2}(x)$, such that 
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln{(\tan^{3/2}(x)+1)}\ \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2z\ln{(1+z^3)}}{1+z^4}\ \mathrm{d}z.
$$
Now, integrals like this are usually amenable to series expansion, [like in this recently resolved question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524358/evaluating-int-01-frac-log-x-log-left1-x4-right1x2dx/539149#539149), so expanding, 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2z\ln{(1+z^3)}}{1+z^4}\ \mathrm{d}z &= 2\int_{0}^{1} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}z^{3k+1}}{k} \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n z^{4n}\ \mathrm{d}z \\ 
&= \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+n+1}}{k(4n+3k+2)}
\end{align}
Unfortunately, as in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/428709/78722) that @Paramanand Singh posted, these double sums seem very difficult to evaluate. Unless there is some other integral transform for your special case, it appears we may have to use those number theoretic techniques.

Comment: That last integral is evaluated [here](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic281.html#p1838).

Comment: Brilliant! Great work.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln{\left(\sqrt{\sin^3{x}}+\sqrt{\cos^3{x}}\right)}dx\\
&=\frac12 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln{\left(\sqrt{\sin^3{x}}+\sqrt{\cos^3{x}}\right)}dx\\
&=\frac34 \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln (\cos x)dx+\frac12 \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln \left(\sqrt{\tan^3x}+1\right)\overset{t^2=\tan x}{dx}\\
&=-\frac{3\pi}8\ln2+\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln(t^2+1)}{t^4+1}dt  +\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln(t+1)}{t^4+1}dt 
+ \int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln\frac{t^2-t+1}{t^2+1}}{t^4+1}dt \tag1
\end{align}
Evaluate
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln(t+1)}{t^4+1}dt \\
=&\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{t^2}{(t^4+1)(yt+1)}dy\ dt\\
=& \int_0^1\left( \frac{y\ln y}{1+y^4} +\frac\pi4\frac{y^3}{1+y^4} +\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}\frac{1-y^2}{1+y^4}\right)dy\\
=&-\frac14G+\frac\pi{16}\ln2+\frac\pi4\ln(\sqrt2+1)\tag2\\
\\
&\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln\frac{t^2-t+1}{t^2+1}}{t^4+1}dt \\
=&\int_0^\infty \int_0^{-\frac\pi6} \frac{2t^2\cos y}{(t^4+1)(t^2+2t\sin y+1)}dy\ dt\\
=& \int_0^{-\frac\pi6}
\left( \frac\pi{\sqrt2}\frac{\cos y}{\cos2y} -\frac\pi4\tan2y+\frac{2y-\pi}{2\cos2y}+\right)dy\\
=& -\frac\pi2\ln(\sqrt2+1)-\frac\pi8\ln2 +\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\ln\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt2}-\frac16G\right)\tag3\\
\end{align}
where [$\int_0^{\frac\pi{12}}\ln(\tan x)dx=-\frac{2G}{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3815818/686284) is used in evaluating the third integral in (3). Substitute (2), (3) and $\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln(t^2+1)}{t^4+1}dt =\frac12G+\frac\pi8\ln2$ into (1) to obtain
$$I=\frac1{12}G+\frac{2\pi}3\ln(\sqrt3+1)-\frac\pi4\ln(\sqrt2+1)-\frac{31\pi}{48}\ln2
$$