# Prove that $\frac{2}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^{2-\sqrt3}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Proof the following
$$\frac{2}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^{2-\sqrt3}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$$

I've tried to use x=tan(u) substitution, but don't know how to proceed with this
$$\frac{2}{3}\int_0^{π/4}\ln(\tan(u))du=\int_0^{π/12}\ln(\tan(u))du$$

Please help

Comment: $$\ln(\tan(u)) = \ln\left(\frac{\sin(u)}{\cos(u)}\right) = \ln(\sin(u)) - \ln(\cos(u))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the change: $u=3x$:
$$\frac{2}{3}\int_0^{π/4}\ln(\tan(u))du=2\int_0^{π/12}\ln(\tan(3x))dx$$
Now look at the accepted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983044/integral-int-0-pi-12-ln-tan-x-dx/) to get:
$$~\displaystyle 2\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{12}} \ln(\tan(3x))dx=\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{12}} \ln(\tan(u))du.$$

Answer (score 3):

Utilize the integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{2(y^2-1)\cos 2t}{y^4+1-2y^2\cos 4t}dy =\ln(\tan t)
$$
to prove

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2-\sqrt3}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx \\= & \int_0^\frac\pi{12}\ln(\tan t)~dt
= \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac\pi{12} }
 \frac{2(y^2-1)\cos 2t}{y^4+1-2y^2\cos 4t}dt \ dy\\= &\ -\frac12\int_0^1\frac1y \tan^{-1}\frac y{1-y^2} dy
= -\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}y^3}y \overset{y^3\to y}{dy}
-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}y}y dy\\=&- \frac23\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}y}ydy 
\overset{ibp}
=\frac23\int_0^1\frac{\ln y}{1+y^2}dy
\end{align}