# Finding $k$ such that $\int_0^{\pi/12} \ln(\tan (3x))\,\mathrm{d}x = k \int_0^{\pi/12} \ln(\tan(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^{\pi/12} \ln(\tan (3x))\,\mathrm{d}x = k \int_0^{\pi/12} \ln(\tan(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$$
> What is $k$?

So I have tried almost every property so far and it has not been helpful, tried the property $f(a+b-x)=f(x)$

$a$ and $b$ being lower and upper limits of an integral for $f(x)$, tried rewriting $\tan(3x)$ to get $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{12}} \ln \left( \frac{3\tan(x)-\tan(x)^3} {1-3\tan(x)^2} \right)\mathrm{d}x$$ but then again I was stuck, how do we evalute this?

Comment: Remark: Just like with $\ln$ common math functions render nicely with the extra backslash, i.e. `$\tan$` gives $\tan$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integral: $\int_0^{\pi/12} \ln(\tan x)\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983044/integral-int-0-pi-12-ln-tan-x-dx)

Comment: Not that I know how to do this another way, but maybe you could use $
\int_0^z\ln(\tan x)\,dx=z\,\ln(\tan z)-\operatorname{Ti}_2(\tan z)
$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the complex representation of the arctangent function
$$\tan^{-1}(t)=\frac{i}{2} \log{\left ( \frac{i+t}{i-t}\right )}$$ the antiderivative is not too difficult.

But, for the fun, consider the series expansions.  In other words,
$$I_1=\int_0^{\frac \pi {12}}\log (\tan (x))\,dx$$
$$\large\color{blue}{I_1=\frac{\pi}{12} \log \left(\frac{\pi }{12 e}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \left(4^n-2\right) \pi^{2
   n+1} \left| B_{2 n}\right| }{3^{2 n+1} 2^{2n+3} n \Gamma (2 n+2)}}$$
$$I_3=\int_0^{\frac \pi {12}}\log (\tan (3x))\,dx$$
$$\large\color{blue}{I_3=\frac{\pi}{12}  \log \left(\frac{\pi }{4 e}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{ \left(4^n-2\right) \pi ^{2 n+1} \left| B_{2
   n}\right| }{3\, 2^{2 n+3}n \Gamma (2 n+2)}}$$

Limit the summation to $p$ terms  of your choice  and compute
$$k_p=\frac {I_3^{(p)}}{I_1^{(p)}}$$
Notice that
$$k_0=\frac{\log \left(\frac{\pi }{4 e}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{\pi }{12 e}\right)}=0.530543 \qquad \qquad \huge\color{red}{!!!}$$

Now a few more accurate values

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & k_p \\
 0 & 0.530543 \\
 1 & 0.502892 \\
 2 & 0.500370 \\
 3 & 0.500056 \\
 4 & 0.500009 \\
 5 & 0.500002 \\
 6 & 0.500000 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: thank you so much, will definitely learn this concept

Answer (score 1):

Now you have found a method to solve the problem, I would like to give you the only method (other than seeking help of WoframAlpha)  I know how to do this type of integral.

First express the function to be integrated as a series, e.g.,
$$\ln\left|\tan\left(x\right)\right|=\ln\left|x\right|+\dfrac{1}{3}x^2+\dfrac{7}{90}x^4+\dfrac{62}{2835}x^6+\dots+\dfrac{2^{2n}\left(2^{2n-1}-1\right)}{n\left(2n\right)!}B_nx^{2n}  \quad\text{for}\quad  0\lt\left|x\right|\lt \dfrac{\pi}{2},$$
where $B_n$ denotes the Bernoulli numbers.

If you do this for both $\space\ln\left|\tan\left(x\right)\right|\space$ and $\space\ln\left|\tan\left(3x\right)\right|,\space$ and then evaluate the two definite integrals, you will get,
$$k=0.5$$

This value of $k$ strongly suggests that there is a some kind of a trick to solve this problem. I believe that is what you have already found, so congratulations! I have no further ideas.

Comment: thanks for this new concept and indeed k is 0.5

Comment: how do you compute this integral after doing the series expansion?

Comment: @GGplay You can integrate the series term by term up to certain number of terms.

Comment: But how to get a closed form after integration term by term?

Comment: @GGplay No, there is no way to obtain a closed form. Even WolframAlpha is unable to do that

Comment: This is false, this integral can be solved analytically. Wolfram is not god.