# How to evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{x}{\sin x}$?

Tags: integration

A well-know representation of the Catalan constant is given by
$$C=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sin x}\,dx.$$
So, I asked myself if there are other values of $x$ that make the integral
$$f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{t}{\sin t}\,dt$$
take well-known closed form values.
Experimenting with Mathematica ([see this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%28x%2F%28sin%28x%29%29%20%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CPi%2F6%7D%29)), I found that
$$f\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{4}{3}C-\frac{\pi}{6} \cosh^{-1}(2).$$
However, I failed to prove this result. So, any help would be very appriciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize
[$\int_0^{\pi/12} \ln(\tan x)\,dx =-\frac{2}3C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3815818/686284) to obtan
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=&\int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{t}{\sin t}\,dt =  \int_0^{\pi/6}t\ d(\ln(\tan\frac t2) )\\
\overset{ibp}=&\ \frac{\pi}6 \ln(\tan\frac{\pi}{12})-\int_0^{\pi/6} \ln(\tan\frac t2) dt
=-\frac{\pi}{6} \cosh^{-1}2+ \frac{4}{3}C\\
\end{align}

Comment: Great thanks, I just corrected two typos.