# Closed-form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\Psi_3(n+1)=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Does the following series or integral have a closed-form

> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\Psi_3(n+1)=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx
> \end{equation}

where $\Psi_3(x)$ is the polygamma function of order $3$.

---

Here is my attempt. Using equation (11) from [Mathworld Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html):
\begin{equation}
\Psi_n(z)=(-1)^{n+1} n!\left(\zeta(n+1)-H_{z-1}^{(n+1)}\right)
\end{equation}
I got
\begin{equation}
\Psi_3(n+1)=6\left(\zeta(4)-H_{n}^{(4)}\right)
\end{equation}
then
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\Psi_3(n+1)&=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\left(\zeta(4)-H_{n}^{(4)}\right)\\
&=6\zeta(4)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_{n}^{(4)}}{n}\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{15}\ln2-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_{n}^{(4)}}{n}\\
\end{align}
From [the answers of this OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk), the integral representation of the latter Euler sum is
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_{n}^{(4)}}{n}&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4\,dx_5}{(1-x_1)(1+x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5)}
\end{align}
or another simpler form
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_{n}^{(4)}}{n}&=-\int_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_4(-x)}{x(1+x)}dx\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_4(-x)}{x}dx+\int_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_4(-x)}{1+x}dx\\
&=\text{Li}_5(-1)-\int_0^{-1}\frac{\text{Li}_4(x)}{1-x}dx\\
\end{align}
I don't know how to continue it, I am stuck. Could anyone here please help me to find the closed-form of the series preferably with elementary ways? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

---

**Edit :**

Using the integral representation of polygamma function
\begin{equation}
\Psi_m(z)=(-1)^m\int_0^1\frac{x^{z-1}}{1-x}\ln^m x\,dx
\end{equation}
then we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\Psi_3(n+1)&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}}{1-x}\ln^3 x\,dx\\
&=-\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n}}{n}\cdot\frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
\end{align}
I am looking for an approach to evaluate the above integral **without** using residue method or double summation.

Comment: Downvote for no reason again! Why the heck this OP got downvoted?? May The Lord forgive your sin (҂⌣̀_⌣́)ᕤ

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Edited**: I have changed the approach as I realised that the use of summation is quite redundant (since the resulting sums have to be converted back to integrals). I feel that this new method is slightly cleaner and more systematic.

We can break up the integral into
\begin{align}
-&\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1+x)}{1-x}{\rm d}x\\
=&\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}{\rm d}x-\int^1_0\frac{(1+x)\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x^2)}{(1+x)(1-x)}{\rm d}x\\
=&\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}{\rm d}x-\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}{\rm d}x-\int^1_0\frac{x\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}{\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{15}{16}\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}{\rm d}x-\frac{1}{16}\int^1_0\frac{x^{-1/2}\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}{\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{15}{16}\frac{\partial^4\beta}{\partial a^3 \partial b}(1,0^{+})-\frac{1}{16}\frac{\partial^4\beta}{\partial a^3 \partial b}(0.5,0^{+})
\end{align}
After differentiating and expanding at $b=0$ (with the help of Mathematica),
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial^4\beta}{\partial a^3 \partial b}(a,0^{+})\\
=&\left[\frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(a+b)}\left(\frac{1}{b}+\mathcal{O}(1)\right)\left(\left(-\frac{\psi_4(a)}{2}+(\gamma+\psi_0(a))\psi_3(a)+3\psi_1(a)\psi_2(a)\right)b+\mathcal{O}(b^2)\right)\right]_{b=0}\\
=&-\frac{1}{2}\psi_4(a)+(\gamma+\psi_0(a))\psi_3(a)+3\psi_1(a)\psi_2(a)
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
-&\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1+x)}{1-x}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\frac{15}{32}\psi_4(1)+\frac{45}{16}\psi_1(1)\psi_2(1)+\frac{1}{32}\psi_4(0.5)+\frac{1}{8}\psi_3(0.5)\ln{2}-\frac{3}{16}\psi_1(0.5)\psi_2(0.5)\\
=&-12\zeta(5)+\frac{3\pi^2}{8}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^4}{8}\ln{2}
\end{align}
The relation between $\psi_{m}(1)$, $\psi_m(0.5)$ and $\zeta(m+1)$ is established easily using the series representation of the polygamma function.

Comment: Interesting alternate approach together with nice reference! +1

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thank you for your compliment.

Comment: Very nice answer. This kind of solution that I'm looking for. I know that if we use the residue approach the solution will be much cleaner and more efficient, but I don't know anything about it. My knowledge in residue is almost zero that's why I love Feynman's style answers to evaluate integral problems. +1 for your answer. I hope I get other interesting approach (ô‿ô)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova If you are interested, I have edited my answer and removed the (redundant) use of summation altogether. The method of evaluation is slightly shorter and more systematic now, if I may say so myself. Thanks.

Comment: Very clever! I love this approach. No double summation's involved. Another way beside using multiple derivative of beta function, we can use generating function
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_{n}x^n=\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}$$to solve the integral. I wish I could give 1000 upvotes for this answer.

Answer (score 21):

\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\psi_3(n+1)}{n}
&=-12\zeta(5)+\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln{2}+\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)
\end{align}

---

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{\pi\csc(\pi z)\psi_3(-z)}{z}$. Then at the positive integers,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\rm Res}(f,n)
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n}\left[\frac{6(-1)^n}{z(z-n)^5}+\frac{6(-1)^n\zeta(2)}{z(z-n)^3}+(-1)^n\frac{(33/2)\zeta(4)+6H_n^{(4)}}{z(z-n)}\right]\\
&=6\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^5}+6\zeta(2)\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}+\frac{33}{2}\zeta(4)\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+6\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}\\
&=-\frac{45}{8}\zeta(5)-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{33}{2}\zeta(4)\ln{2}+6\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}
\end{align}
At zero,
$${\rm Res}(f,0)=24\zeta(5)$$
At the negative integers,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\rm Res}(f,-n)
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\psi_3(n)}{n}\\
&=6\zeta(4)\ln{2}-6\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_{n-1}^{(4)}}{n}\\
&=\frac{45}{8}\zeta(5)+6\zeta(4)\ln{2}+6\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n}H_{n}^{(4)}}{n}\\
\end{align}
Since the sum of residues is zero,
\begin{align}
12\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n}H_{n}^{(4)}}{n}=-24\zeta(5)+\frac{21}{2}\zeta(4)\ln{2}+\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\
\end{align}
This implies that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\psi_3(n+1)}{n}
&=-12\zeta(5)+\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln{2}+\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)
\end{align}
Refer to [this paper](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf) if you have any doubts.

Comment: I'm looking for elementary method, without using complex analysis. Still I upvote you, +1. Anyway, could you please give me references or link of papers to evaluate sum of harmonic series using residue? I mean simpler than cited link. It looks like that technique very useful & easy. Thank you (ô‿ô)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova I actually picked up this method from the cited link, and it seems that this paper is the only paper I have seen online that elaborates on this method to such a great degree. Of course, if I remember correctly, users like Random Variable and Galactus have also used this method quite a few times to compute Euler sums on I&S, and you might want to refer to their work there as well. Unfortunately, this method is not without its limitations, for example, it cannot be used to evaluate $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n^2}$

Comment: Okay, could you please elaborate this part:
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\rm Res}(f,n)
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n}\left[\frac{6(-1)^n}{z(z-n)^5}+\frac{6(-1)^n\zeta(2)}{z(z-n)^3}+(-1)^n\frac{(33/2)\zeta(4)+6H_n^{(4)}}{z(z-n)}\right]\\
&=6\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^5}+6\zeta(2)\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}+\frac{33}{2}\zeta(4)\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+6\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}
\end{align}
I don't understand the first & second line?

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova I expanded $\pi\csc(\pi z)\psi_3(-z)$ as a Laurent series about the positive integers. The Laurent series of both functions are found in the paper, and they can also be derived rather easily.

Comment: No doubts! :-) Nice answer, good reference! +1

Answer (score 7):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3x}{1-x}\ dx&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}\ln^3x}{1-x}\ dx=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(\zeta(4)-H_n^{(4)}\right)\\
&=-6\ln2\zeta(4)-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}\tag{1}
\end{align} 
evaluating the sum:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}&=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_4(-x)}{x(1+x)}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_4(-x)}{x}\ dx-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_4(-x)}{1+x}\ dx}_{\text{IBP}}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_5(-1)-\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4(-1)+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)}{x}\ dx}_{\text{IBP}}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_5(-1)-\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4(-1)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)+\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=-\frac{15}{16}\zeta(5)+\frac78\ln2\zeta(4)-\frac38\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-x)}{x}\ dx \tag{2}
\end{align}
and the last integral:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-x)}{x}\ dx&=\int_0^1\frac1x\left(\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\right)^2\ dx\\
&=\underbrace{\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x^2)}{x}\ dx}_{x^2=y}-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx+\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=\frac98\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=\frac98\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\int_0^1x^{n-1}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ dx-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ dx\\
&=\frac98\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{n}-\frac{H_n}{n^2}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{2n}-\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac98\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac98\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}\\
&=\frac58\zeta(2\zeta(3)+\frac78\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}\\
&=\frac58\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac78\left(3)\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\right)+2\left(\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)\right)\\
&=\frac34\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{17}{16}\zeta(5)\tag{3}
\end{align}

plugging $(3)$ in $(2)$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}=\frac78\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac38\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-2\zeta(5)$$
plugging this result in $(1)$ we have
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3x}{1-x}\ dx=12\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{4}\ln2\zeta(4)-\frac94\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

Answer (score 7):

Preprint source: [A simple strategy of calculating two alternating harmonic series generalizations by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333339284_A_simple_strategy_of_calculating_two_alternating_harmonic_series_generalizations)

The following generalizations with solutions are proposed by Cornel Ioan Valean, using ideas about symmetry from his book, ***(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series***.

(First main result) Let $m\ge2$ be a positive integer. The following equalities hold:
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(m)}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)\log\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{1}{2}\biggr(m\zeta (m+1)-2\log (2) \left(1-2^{1-m}\right) \zeta (m)-\sum_{k=1}^{m-2} \left(1-2^{-k}\right)\left(1-2^{1+k-m}\right)\zeta (k+1)\zeta (m-k)\biggr),
\end{equation*}
where $H_n^{(m)}=1+\frac{1}{2^m}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^m}$ represents the $n$th generalized harmonic number of order $m$ and $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.

**Proof:**
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(m)}}{n}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^m}=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\int_0^1 x^{k-1}\log^{m-1}(x)\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1 \log^{m-1}(x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k-1}\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)\log\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\int_x^1 \frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)}{(1+y)(1-x)}\textrm{d}y \right)\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\int_0^y \frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)}{(1+y)(1-x)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\overset{x=yz}{=}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{y\log^{m-1}(y z)}{(1+y)(1-yz)}\textrm{d}z \right)\textrm{d}y
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2\cdot(m-1)!}\left(\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{y\log^{m-1}(x y)}{(1+y)(1-x y)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y+\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\log^{m-1}(x y)}{(1+x)(1-x y)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2\cdot(m-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{((1 + x) (1 + y) - (1 - x y))\log^{m-1}(x y)}{(1+x)(1+y)(1-x y)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2\cdot(m-1)!}\left(\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\log^{m-1}(x y)}{1-x y}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y-\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\log^{m-1}(x y)}{(1+x)(1+y)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2\cdot(m-1)!}\biggr(\int_0^1\left(\int_0^y \frac{\log^{m-1}(x)}{(1-x)y}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{k} \frac{\log^k(x)\log^{m-k-1}(y)}{(1+x)(1+y)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\biggr)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2\cdot(m-1)!}\biggr(\int_0^1\left(\int_x^1 \frac{\log^{m-1}(x)}{(1-x)y}\textrm{d}y \right)\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
- \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{k}\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\log^k(x)\log^{m-k-1}(y)}{(1+x)(1+y)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\biggr)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^m}{2\cdot(m-1)!}\left(\int_0^1\frac{\log^m(x)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{k}\int_0^1\frac{\log^{m-k-1}(y)}{1+y}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\log^k(x)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^m}{2\cdot(m-1)!}\biggr((-1)^m m!\zeta (m+1) +(-1)^{m-1} 2\log (2)(1-2^{1-m}) (m-1)!\zeta (m)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
+\sum_{k=1}^{m-2}\binom{m-1}{k}\int_0^1\frac{\log^{m-k-1}(y)}{1+y}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\log^k(x)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\biggr)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{1}{2}\biggr(m\zeta (m+1)-2\log (2) \left(1-2^{1-m}\right) \zeta (m)-\sum_{k=1}^{m-2} \left(1-2^{-k}\right)\left(1-2^{1+k-m}\right)\zeta (k+1)\zeta (m-k)\biggr).
\end{equation*}

**A few cases of the first generalization**

For $m=2$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}=\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)\zeta(2);
\end{equation*}
For $m=3$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n}=\frac{19}{16}\zeta(4)-\frac{3}{4}\log(2)\zeta(3);
\end{equation*}
For $m=4$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(4)}}{n}=2\zeta(5)-\frac{3}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{7}{8}\log(2)\zeta(4);
\end{equation*}
For $m=5$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(5)}}{n}=\frac{111}{64}\zeta(6)-\frac{9}{32}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{15}{16}\log(2)\zeta(5);
\end{equation*}
For $m=6$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(6)}}{n}=3\zeta(7)-\frac{15}{32}\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{32}\zeta(3)\zeta(4)-\frac{31}{32}\log(2)\zeta(6).
\end{equation*}

(Second main result) Let $m\ge2$ be a positive integer. The following equalities hold:

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(m)}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)\log\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=m\zeta (m+1)- 2^{-m} \left(1-2^{-m+1}\right) \log(2 ) \zeta (m) -\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\beta(k+1)\beta(m-k)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-\sum_{k=1}^{m-2}2^{- m-1}(1-2^{-k})(1-2^{-m+k+1}) \zeta (k+1)\zeta (m-k),
\end{equation*}
where $H_n^{(m)}=1+\frac{1}{2^m}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^m}$ represents the $n$th generalized harmonic number of order $m$, $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function and $\beta$ designates the Dirichlet beta function.

**Proof:**
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(m)}}{n}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^m}=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\int_0^1 x^{k-1}\log^{m-1}(x)\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}x^{k-1}\log^{m-1}(x)\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)\log\left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x=\frac{2(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\int_x^1 \frac{y\log^{m-1}(x)}{(1+y^2)(1-x)}\textrm{d}y \right)\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{2(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\int_0^y \frac{y\log^{m-1}(x)}{(1+y^2)(1-x)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\overset{x=y z}{=}\frac{2(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{y^2\log^{m-1}(yz)}{(1+y^2)(1-yz)}\textrm{d}z \right)\textrm{d}y
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\left(\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{y^2\log^{m-1}(xy)}{(1+y^2)(1-xy)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y+\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x^2\log^{m-1}(xy)}{(1+x^2)(1-xy)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{((1+x^2)(1+y^2)-(1-(x y)^2))\log^{m-1}(xy)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1-xy)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\biggr(\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\log^{m-1}(xy)}{1-xy}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y-\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\log^{m-1}(xy)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x y\log^{m-1}(xy)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\biggr)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\biggr(\int_0^1 \frac{\log^{m}(x)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{k}\int_0^1  \frac{\log^{m-k-1}(y)}{1+y^2}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\log^k(x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{k}\int_0^1\frac{y \log^{m-k-1}(y)}{1+y^2} \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\log^k(x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x \right)\textrm{d}y\biggr)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=m\zeta (m+1)- 2^{-m} \left(1-2^{-m+1}\right) \log(2 ) \zeta (m) -\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\beta(k+1)\beta(m-k)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-\sum_{k=1}^{m-2}2^{- m-1}(1-2^{-k})(1-2^{-m+k+1}) \zeta (k+1)\zeta (m-k).
\end{equation*}

**A few cases of the second generalization**

For $m=2$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(2)}}{n}=2\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{8}\log(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{\pi}{2}G;
\end{equation*}
For $m=3$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(3)}}{n}=\frac{199}{128}\zeta (4)-\frac{3}{32} \log (2)\zeta (3)-G^2;
\end{equation*}
For $m=4$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(4)}}{n}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=4\zeta(5)-\frac{3}{128}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{7}{128}\log(2)\zeta(4)+\frac{\pi^5}{192}-\frac{\pi^3}{16}G-\frac{\pi}{1536}\psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right);
\end{equation*}
For $m=5$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(5)}}{n}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{5151}{2048}\zeta(6)-\frac{15}{512}\log(2)\zeta(5)-\frac{9}{1024}\zeta^2(3)+\frac{15}{8}\zeta(4)G-\frac{1}{384}G\psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right);
\end{equation*}
For $m=6$, 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(6)}}{n}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=6\zeta(7)-\frac{15}{2048}\zeta (2) \zeta (5)-\frac{21}{2048}\zeta (3) \zeta (4)-\frac{31}{2048}\log(2)\zeta(6)+\frac{3}{2560}\pi^7-\frac{5}{768}\pi^5 G
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{\pi^3}{12288}\psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{\pi}{491520}\psi^{(5)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right).
\end{equation*}

The following equalities have been necessary during calculations:
\begin{equation*}
i) \ \int_0^1\frac{\log^m(x)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x=(-1)^m m!\zeta(m+1);
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
ii) \ \int_0^1\frac{\log^m(x)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x=(-1)^m (1-2^{-m})m!\zeta(m+1);
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
iii) \ \int_0^1\frac{\log^m(x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x=(-1)^m m!\beta(m+1);
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
iv) \ \int_0^1\frac{x\log^m(x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x=(-1)^m 2^{-(m+1)} (1-2^{-m})m!\zeta(m+1),
\end{equation*}
where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function and $\beta$ represents the Dirichlet beta function.

**Proof:**
The results are obtained immediately if we use geometric series.

**An important observation:** the strategy presented above works for the more general case 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{kn}^{(m)}}{n}=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)\log\left(\frac{1+x^k}{2}\right)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x,
\end{equation*}
where $k\ge1$, $m\ge2$ are positive integers.

Comment: Note that a similar general equality, but where $m$ is now in the denominator of the binomial sum, is,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}^{(1)}}{(n+1)^m}z^{n}=\frac{(-1)^m}{(m-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\displaystyle \log^{m-1}(x)\log\left(1-z\,x\right)}{1-z\,x}\textrm{d}x$$
for $-1\leq z\leq 1$ and integer $m\geq1$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

We can have a nice generalization,

From

$$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \overline{H}_n x^n$$

We have

$$I_m=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^{m-1}x}{1-x}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \overline{H}_n \int_0^1 x^n\ln^{m-1}x\ dx$$

$$=(-1)^{m-1}(m-1)!\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\overline{H}_n}{(n+1)^m}$$

$$=(-1)^{m-1}(m-1)!\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\overline{H}_{n-1}}{n^m}$$

$$=(-1)^{m-1}(m-1)!\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\overline{H}_n+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}{n^m}$$

$$=(-1)^{m-1}(m-1)!\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\overline{H}_n}{n^m}-\eta(m+1)\right]$$

Substitute

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\overline H_n}{n^m} = \ln 2\zeta (m)  - \frac{1}{2} m \zeta (m + 1) + \eta (m + 1) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^m \eta (i) \eta (m - i + 1)$$

We get

> $$I_m=(-1)^{m}(m-1)!\left[\frac{1}{2} m \zeta (m + 1)-\ln 2\zeta (m)    - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^m \eta (i) \eta (m - i + 1)\right]$$

---

The generalization $\displaystyle \small \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\overline H_n}{n^m}$ can be found [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82155486.pdf) (see Theorem 3.5 on page 9).

Answer (score 3):

Computation of $\displaystyle U=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx$

\begin{align*}
U&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\left[\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\ln(1+x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\left(\int_0^x\frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&=-6\zeta(4)\ln 2+\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1+t)(1+x)}-\frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1+t)(1-tx)}\right)\,dt\,dx\\
&=-6\zeta(4)\ln 2+6\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt\right)\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\right)+\\
&2\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 t}{1+t}\,dt\right)\left(\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx\right)-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t(1+t)}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\,dt\\
&=-\frac{33}{2}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t(1+t)}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\,dt\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{33}{2}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\left[\ln\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=-\frac{45}{2}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=-\frac{45}{2}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+24\zeta(5)-U\\
U&=\boxed{-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+12\zeta(5)}
\end{align*}

Comment: Impressive and clever. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**Different approach using only series manipulations.**

By using the identity

$$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \overline{H}_n x^n$$ which can be easily proved by series-expanding the numerator and denominator.

Multiply  both sides by $\ln^3x$ then $\int_0^1$ we get

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3x}{1-x}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \overline{H}_n\int_0^1 x^n \ln^3x\ dx=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n}{(n+1)^4}=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_{n-1}}{n^4}$$

Now use $\overline{H}_{n-1}=\overline{H}_n+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

$$ \Longrightarrow I=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n}{n^4}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^5}=\frac{45}{8}\zeta(5)-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n}{n^4}\tag1$$

---

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n}{n^4}=1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n}{n^4}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_{2n}}{(2n)^4}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^4}$$

By writing $\overline{H}_{2n}=H_{2n}-H_n$ and $\overline{H}_{2n+1}=H_{2n+1}-H_n$ we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_{2n}}{(2n)^4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{(2n)^4}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{n^4}+\frac7{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^4}=\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^4}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^4}$$

$$=\color{blue}{-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^4}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^4}$$

$$=\color{blue}{-1+\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n+1}}{(n+1)^4}+\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n+1}}{(n+1)^4}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^4}$$

$$=\color{blue}{-1-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{n^4}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^4}$$

Combine the two sums,

$$\Longrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n}{n^4}=\frac{15}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^4}$$

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540515) we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{(n+a)^{2}}=\left(\gamma + \psi(a) \right) \psi_{1}(a) -  \frac{\psi_{2}(a)}{2}$$

Differentiate with respect to $a$ twice then set $a=1/2$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^4}=\frac{31}{8}\zeta(5)-\frac{15}{8}\ln2\zeta(4)-\frac78\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

Substituting this result along with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}=3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$ gives

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n}{n^4}=-\frac{17}{16}\zeta(5)+\frac{15}{8}\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac38\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\tag2$$

Finally plug $(2)$ in $(1)$ we get

> $$I=12\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{4}\ln2\zeta(4)-\frac94\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

---

**Edit**

Another way to calculate $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n}{n^3}$ is to use the generalization

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\overline H_k}{k^m} = \zeta (m) \log 2 - \frac{1}{2} m \zeta (m + 1) + \eta (m + 1) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^m \eta (i) \eta (m - i + 1).$$

where $\eta (s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n - 1}}{n^s} = (1 - 2^{1 - s}) \zeta (s)$ is the *Dirichlet eta function* and $\zeta (s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$ is the *Riemann zeta function*.

With $m=4$ we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n}{n^4}=-\frac{17}{16}\zeta(5)+\frac{15}{8}\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac38\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

The generalization can be found [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82155486.pdf) (see Theorem 3.5 on page 9).

Comment: The *skew-harmonic number* $\overline H_n$ is a beautiful new tool.

Comment: @omegadot I agree and I recently started using it. it simplifies some tough problems.

Answer (score 0):

The following proof is very simple and short but it works for only the odd powers of $\ln(x):$

By integrating

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac1x\right)=-\frac{\ln^2(x)}{2}-2\eta(2)$$

repeatedly, we get

$$\operatorname{Li}_{2a}(-x)+\operatorname{Li}_{2a}\left(-\frac1x\right)=-2\sum_{k=0}^a \frac{\eta(2a-2k)}{(2k)!}\ln^{2k}(x)$$

Using the integral form of the polylogarithm function, we have

\begin{gather*}
\operatorname{Li}_{2a}(-x)+\operatorname{Li}_{2a}\left(-\frac1x\right)\\
=\frac{-1}{(2a-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{-x\ln^{2a-1}(y)}{1+xy}\mathrm{d}y-\frac1{(2a-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{-\frac1{x}\ln^{2a-1}(y)}{1+\frac{y}{x}}\mathrm{d}y\\
=\frac{1}{(2a-1)!}\int_0^1\ln^{2a-1}(y)\left(\frac{x}{1+xy}+\frac{1}{x+y}\right)\mathrm{d}y\\
=\frac{1}{(2a-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{(1+2xy+x^2)\ln^{2a-1}(y)}{(1+xy)(x+y)}\mathrm{d}y.
\end{gather*}
and so
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\frac{(1+2xy+x^2)\ln^{2a-1}(y)}{(1+xy)(x+y)}\mathrm{d}y=-2(2a-1)!\sum_{k=0}^a \frac{\eta(2a-2k)}{(2k)!}\ln^{2k}(x).
\end{equation}

Divide the latter identity by $1+x$ using $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^s(x)}{1+x}dx=(-1)^s s!\eta(s+1),$ we get

$$-2(2a-1)!\sum_{k=0}^a \eta(2a-2k)\eta(2k+1)=\int_0^1\ln^{2a-1}(y)\left(\int_0^1\frac{1+2xy+x^2}{(1+xy)(x+y)(1+x)}\mathrm{d}x\right)\mathrm{d}y$$

$$=\int_0^1\ln^{2a-1}(y)\left(\frac{2\ln(1+y)}{1-y}+\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}-\frac{\ln(y)}{1-y}-\frac{2\ln(2)}{1-y}\right)\mathrm{d}y$$

$$=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a-1}(x)\ln(1+x)}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x-(2a-1)!\eta(2a+1)-(2a)!\zeta(2a+1)$$
$$+2(2a-1)!\ln(2)\zeta(2a)$$

$$\Longrightarrow \int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a-1}(x)\ln(1+x)}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=(2a-1)!\left(\frac12(2a-4^{-a}+1)\zeta(2a+1)-\ln(2)\zeta(2a)-\sum_{k=0}^a \eta(2a-2k)\eta(2k+1)\right).$$