# Find the closed form of $\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(3)}}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

where $H_n$ is the harmonic number and can be defined as:

$H_n=1+\frac12+\frac13+...+\frac1n$

$H_n^{(3)}=1+\frac1{2^3}+\frac1{3^3}+...+\frac1{n^3}$

I managed to prove 
$\quad\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=\frac{21}{32}\zeta(5)-\frac34\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\quad$ using logarithmic integral and couple harmonic identities. other approaches are much appreciated.

you can find a different solution by Cornel in his book (**Almost impossible integrals, sum and series**).

Comment: @ Ali Shather Over the last couple of weeks  you have provided interesting results for special cases. What about explaining your general method and showing its capabiities in solving a class of problems, e.g. for $S(p,q) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k H_{k}^{(p)}/k^q$ and answer questins such as "Which combinations of $,p$ and $q$ permit closed expressions?" and "What is new in these results?"

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze thank you. actually I solved these sums over a year ago and I posted some of them on my facebook group ( harmonic series) but I've been posting them here lately as I've just learned LaTex. about your question, I know that Bastien derived the generalization for S(1,q) here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.7662.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0teDyTR0jeTrvjnSlAraDYDAU9496FPdmwdkk70YY1_NmDLu8yxKXDr9A where q is even.

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang and couple days ago Cornel derived the generalization  for S( p,1) here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333339284_A_simple_strategy_of_calculating_two_alternating_harmonic_series_generalizations?fbclid=IwAR26U6bDipBdciDHMCAVmXQkyyriVcqdHM0cDzE2hdexicszdi4-5Lv2UfI. The generalization of S(p,q) is extremely hard and its not in the mathematical literature yet. I do not see myself good enough to investigate it and  I am just focused on providing new solutions to particular cases.

Comment: @ Ali Shather From the work of Bastien (thanks for the hint) I conclude that $S(1,5)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{H_{k}}{k^5}$ is the first sum which seems not to have a closed form (in terms). So this is a real challenge.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze no problem. Yes it's pretty tough and that's why mathematicians still struggle with it.

Comment: @ Ali Shather There's no need to repeat what I just wrote. If you know more about this specific problem, please reveal your knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Divide both sides of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^nH_n^{(3)}=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(z)}{1-z}\ $   by $z$ then integrate from $z=0$ to $x$, we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^nH_n^{(3)}}{n}=\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)\tag{1}.$$

Replace $x$ with $-x$ in(1), then divide both sides by $x$ and integrate from $0$ to $1$, we get

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(3)}}{n^2}&=\operatorname{Li}_5(-1)-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)}{x}\ dx}_{IBP}-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_5(-1)+\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)-\frac32\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=\frac38\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{15}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac32\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-x)}{x}\ dx\\
\end{align}
I proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934981/closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n1n-psi-3n1-int-01-frac/3236084#3236084)
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-x)}{x}\ dx=\frac34\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{17}{16}\zeta(5)
\end{align}
Plugging this integral back in, we obtain

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=\frac{21}{32}\zeta(5)-\frac34\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

---

**BONUS:**

By setting $x=-1$ in (1) we have

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n}=\frac34\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{19}{16}\zeta(4)$$