# Logarithmic twin integrals $\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1\pm x}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Here is what I have done

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}dx\\
=&\int_0^1\frac{(1+x)(1+x^2) \log(x)\log(1-x^4)}{1-x^4} \ dx\\
&-\int_0^1\frac{(1+x)\log(x)\log(1-x^2)}{1-x^2} \ dx
\end{align}
and, then, after letting $x^4\mapsto x$ and $x^2\mapsto x$ respectively, use the beta function. Similarly we proceed with the second twin and we are done.

*Please teach me another ways that only use real analysis*.

Above also answers the first integral [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013605/how-to-evaluate-int-01-frac-lnx-ln1x21-xdx-and-int-01-frac-ln)

Comment: You may find this interesting 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524358/evaluating-int-01-frac-log-x-log-left1-x4-right1x2dx

Comment: @BennettGardiner you may use there the same technique I show here.

Comment: @BennettGardiner The valid solutions there seem to get reduced to the same beta story function, sooner or later. I'd like something else, a revolutionary approach, some different ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $K_{\pm} = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1\pm t}dt$ and integrate the twins as follows
\begin{align}
I_\pm =&\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1\pm x}dx \\
=& \int_0^1 \ln(1+x^2)\> d\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1\pm t}dt\right)\\
=& \>\ln2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1\pm t}dt -\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{1+x^2}\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1\pm t}\overset{t=xy}{dt}\right)dx\\
 =& \>\ln2 K_{\pm}-2\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{x^2\ln(xy)}{(1+x^2)(1\pm xy)}dy\>dx\\
 =& \>\ln2 K_{\pm} + 2\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac1{1+y^2}
\bigg( \frac{(1\mp xy)\ln(xy)}{1+x^2}
-\frac{\overset{t=xy}{\ln(xy)}}{1\pm xy} \bigg)dx\>dy\\
 =& \>\ln2 K_{\pm} \pm 2\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{1+x^2} \overset{x^2\to x}{dx}\int_0^1\frac {2y}{1+y^2}dy\\
&+ 4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} dx\int_0^1\frac 1{1+y^2}dy-\int_0^1 \frac{2}{y(1+y^2)}\left(\int_0^y \frac{\ln t}{1\pm t}dt\right)
dy\\
= & \>\ln2 K_{\pm} \pm 2\left(\frac14K_+\right)\ln2
+4\>(-G)\>\frac\pi4
 - \int_0^1 d\left(\ln\frac{y^2}{1+y^2}\right)\int_0^y \frac{\ln t}{1\pm t}dt\\
=& \>2\ln2 K_{\pm}\pm \frac12 \ln2 K_+ -\pi G+2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2y}{1\pm y}-I_{\pm}\\
\end{align}
Substitute $K_- =-\frac{\pi^2}6$, $K_+ =-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$, $\int_0^1  \frac{\ln^2y}{1-y}dy=2\zeta(3)$, $\int_0^1  \frac{\ln^2y}{1+y}dy=\frac32\zeta(3)$ into above expression to arrive at
\begin{align}
&I_-=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}dx 
= -\frac{3\pi^2}{16}\ln2-\frac\pi2 G+2\zeta(3)\\
&I_+=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}dx 
=-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\ln2-\frac\pi2 G+\frac32\zeta(3)
\end{align}