# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \operatorname{Li}_2(1 - x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, special-functions

How to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \operatorname{Li}_2(1 - x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx$$

My try to integrate
$$\text{I}=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \operatorname{Li}_2(1 - x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx$$

\begin{aligned}
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x) \ln(1 + x^2)}{1 - x} \, dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x) \ln(1 + x^2)}{1 - x^2} \, dx \\
&\quad -\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \ln(x) \ln(1 + x^2)}{1 - x^2} \, dx
\end{aligned}

Can someone help me to integrate last two integrals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \operatorname{Li}_2(1 - x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx
\overset{ibp}=-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln x\ln(1 + x^2)}{1 - x} \, dx \\
\end{aligned}
where the integral on the right hand side is given by
[$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln x\ln(1 + x^2)}{1 - x} \, dx= -\frac{3\pi^2}{16}\ln2-\frac\pi2 G+2\zeta(3) $$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4250782/686284)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1\frac{x\text{Li}_2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+x^2}\left(\int_0^x\frac{\ln t}{1-t}dt+\zeta(2)\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2\ln(tx)}{(1+x^2)(1-tx)}dtdx+\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\ln 2\\
&\int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln(tx)}{(1-tx)(1+t^2)}-\frac{\ln(tx)+tx\ln(tx)}{(1+t^2)(1+x^2)}\right)dtdx+\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\ln 2\\
&\overset{\text{Fubini}}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{t(1+t^2)}\left(\int_0^t\frac{\ln z}{1-z}dz\right)dt+\frac{\pi\text{G}}{2}-\ln 2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{x\ln x}{1+x^2}dx}_{u=x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\ln 2\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac{\zeta(2)\ln 2}{2}-2\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t^2)\ln t}{1-t}dt +\frac{\pi\text{G}}{2}+\frac{5}{8}\zeta(2)\ln 2\\
&=\frac{9\zeta(2)\ln 2}{8}-2\zeta(3) +\frac{\pi\text{G}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t^2)\ln t}{1-t}dt
\end{align}

On the other hand,
\begin{align}J&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\ln(1+x^2)\text{Li}_2(1-x)\Big]_0^1-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}J&=\frac{9\zeta(2)\ln 2}{8}-2\zeta(3) +\frac{\pi\text{G}}{2}-J\\
&=\frac{9\zeta(2)\ln 2}{16}-\zeta(3) +\frac{\pi\text{G}}{4}=\boxed{\frac{3\pi^2\ln 2}{32}-\zeta(3) +\frac{\pi\text{G}}{4}}\\
\end{align}