# Logarithmic integral $\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln x\ln (1-x^{2})}{1+x^{2}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

> Evaluate the integral in a closed-form :
>
> $$I=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln x\ln (1-x^{2})}{1+x^{2}}\mathrm dx$$

My attempt :

After put $x=\tan y$ we obtain:

$$I=\int_0^{\frac{π}{4}}\ln (\tan x)\ln (1-\tan^{2} x)dx$$

$$1-\tan^{2} x=(1+\tan x)(1-\tan x)$$
$$\ln (1+\tan x)=\ln(\sin x+\cos x)-\ln(\cos x)=\ln (\cos (\frac{π}{4}-x))-\ln (\cos x)$$

Also:

$$\ln (1-\tan x)=\ln(\cos x-\sin x)-\ln(\cos x)=\ln (\cos (\frac{π}{4}+x))-\ln (\cos x)$$

So:

$$\ln (\tan x)\ln (1-\tan^{2} x)$$

$$=(\ln (\sin x)-\ln(\cos x)(\ln(\cos (\frac{π}{4}-x))-\ln (\cos x))(\ln(\cos (\frac{π}{4}+x))-\ln(\cos x))$$

Now I have many integrals. How can I evaluate them? Let me know if anyone has other ideas.

Comment: Split the logarithm in two, and use the values given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2972249/515527 It won't look nice.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with current answers given which discourages you from [accepting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one of them, to show future users that this question has been answered? If so, please say what could be improved.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by *Zacky* the solution may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953815/evaluating-int-01-ln1x2-lnx2x3-fracdx1x2/2972249#2972249) given by *pisco*. Adopting the notation they use there we see that

\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx+\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx\\
&=I_{ab}+I_{ac}
\end{align*}

In the end of their post they get that

\begin{align*}
I_{ab}&=\Im\left(\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)\right)-\frac{\pi^3}{128}-\frac\pi{32}\log^2(2)\\
I_{ac}&=-3\Im\left(\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)\right)+\frac{11\pi^3}{128}+\frac{3\pi}{32}\log^2(2)-2G\log(2)
\end{align*}

Thus,

> $$\small\therefore~I~=~\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\log(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx~=~-2\Im\left(\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)\right)+\frac{5\pi^3}{64}+\frac\pi{16}\log^2(2)-2G\log(2)$$

Comment: @clathratus Good call!

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1-x^4)}{1+x^2}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx
\end{align}
The first integral was nicely done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/539149) by *Bennett Gardiner*.
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1-x^4)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac{\pi^3}{16}-3G\ln2$$
and I managed to calculate the second integral [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3211825).
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac{3\pi^3}{32}+\frac{\pi}8\ln^22-\ln2~G-2\text{Im}\operatorname{Li_3}(1+i)$$
Thus $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}\ dx=2\text{Im}\operatorname{Li_3}(1+i)-\frac{\pi^3}{32}-\frac{\pi}8\ln^22-2\ln2~G$$

Comment: Interesting. Combining our two results we can conclude that $$\Im\left[\operatorname{Li}_3(1+i)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)\right]~=~\frac{3\pi}{32}\log^2(2)+\frac{7\pi^3}{128}$$ Which seems to work out numerically.

Comment: @mrtaurho we can conclude this relation without comparing the two result, we can just use the tri-logarithmic identity: $$\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-\frac1x\right)=\frac16\ln^3x-\frac12\ln^2x\ln(1-x)+\zeta(2)\ln x+\zeta(3)$$

Comment: Then let's call it a *validation* of this particular Trilogarithmic identity. But which argument do you chose to obtain the given equality? I could not figure it out.

Comment: Sorry mrtaurho I mean let $x=1+i$

Comment: That explains a lot, though. It didn't work out with $x=i$ at all (I tried `^^`). Thank you nevertheless!

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I remember I did it before and thought it was i not 1+i.

Answer (score 2):

Presented below is a self-contained evaluation. Let $J=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx
\overset{x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}}= J
-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx-2G\ln2+\frac{\pi^3}{16}\\
&\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx
\overset{(0,1)+\overset{x\to 1/x}{(1,\infty)}} = 2J -2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx+\frac{\pi^3}{16}
\end{align}

Eliminate $J$ to get

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx
=\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx-K-2G\ln2+\frac{\pi^3}{32}
\tag1$$

where $K=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx =2\text{Im}\>\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)
$. Also

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx
=\frac12 K-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln\frac x{1-x}}{1+x^2}dx +\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1+x^2}dx\tag2
$$

Then, (1) + (2)

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx 
=-2\text{Im}\>\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)-2G\ln2+\frac{\pi^3}{16} +\frac12 A \tag3$$

where
\begin{align}
A =& \int_0^1 \underset{t=1-x}{\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x^2}}dx- \int_0^1\underset{t=\frac x{1-x}}{\frac{\ln\frac x{1-x}}{1+x^2}}dx +\underset{t=1+x}{
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x^2}}dx \\
 =& \int_0^\infty {\frac{4t \ln^2 t}{4+t^4}}dt
\overset{t^2=2u}= \frac14 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(2u)}{1+u^2}du
 = \frac{\pi}{8}\ln^22+\frac{\pi^3}{32}
\end{align}

Plug into (3) to obtain
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx  =-2\text{Im}\>\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right) -2G\ln2
+\frac{\pi}{16}\ln^22+\frac{5\pi^3}{64}$$