# A reason for $ 64\int_0^1 \left(\frac \pi 4+\arctan t\right)^2\cdot \log t\cdot\frac 1{1-t^2}\; dt =-\pi^4$ ...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, polylogarithm

*Question:* How to show the relation
$$
J:=\int_0^1 \left(\frac \pi 4+\arctan t\right)^2\cdot \log t\cdot\frac 1{1-t^2}\; dt 
=-\frac 1{64}\pi^4
$$
(using a "minimal industry" of relations, possibly remaining inside the real analysis)?

So i have found a solution to the problem, it is part of my solution for
[math.stackexchange.com - questions - 3854736](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3854736/challenging-problem-calculate-int-02-pix2-cosx-operatornameli-2-cos),
but not a satisfactory solution. "There should be more", explaining why there is a "clean result" for the integral.

Here, i am not strictly interested in a computational approach. I just want to share this with the community in these days of isolation. Any idea to attack this, or a *related* integral involving "three log factors" is welcome. (Well, the $\arctan$ is a sort of $\log$ in a sense that i don't want to define closer, see below.) Computations may be safely done "modulo integrals involving two or one log factor". But an illuminating, short way to show the above formula for $J$ would be wonderful.

---

*Motivation:* The above relation appeared as i tried to solve the integral posted at the above link:

> Calculate $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} x^2\; \cos x \cdot\operatorname{Li}_2(\cos x)\; dx$ .

After several simplifications and substitutions, it turns out that the above integral is related to integrals of the shape

- $\int_0^1\log t\; R(t)\; dt$ ,  and
- $\int_0^1\arctan t\cdot \log t\; R(t)\; dt$ ,  and
- $\int_0^1\arctan^2 t\cdot \log t\; R(t)\; dt$ ,
- and "similar" expressions.

Here $R$ is in each case a (rather simple) rational function.
(The more log and/or arctangent factors, the higher the computational complexity.)

I could compute more or less *algorithmically* most of the the needed integrals to solve the linked problem, all of them but the integral
$$
K=\int_0^1\arctan^2 t\cdot\log t\cdot\frac2{1-t^2}\; dt\ ,
$$
which turned out to be very hard to attack with the methods of real analysis.
Computing this integral is more or less equivalent to computing $J$, and the question wants $J$ instead, since we have a "clean formula", so that some speculation about a "clever substitution" may be accepted.

My solution (for $K$) works in complex analysis, the first step is to write
$$
\int_0^1 =\int_0^i+\int_i^1\ ,
$$
then parametrize the first integral using a linear path, the second one using a path on the unit circle.

---

*Some comments:* I will say some more words, because the situation is rich in coincidences. Since a numerical evidence is the simplest and shortes way to present (instead of showing how to show), i will use this method to at least list the coincidences. Many equalities below are "equivalent" (modulo computation of integrals of lower complexity) to the formula for $J$.

- First of all, a numerical experiment using pari/gp delivers some connection between $K$ and a "cousin" of $J$:

  ```
    ? 2 * intnum( t=0, 1, atan(t)^2 * log(t) / (1-t^2) )
    %88 = -0.357038604620289042902893412499686912781214141574556097366337
    ? real(intnum( t=0, I, (pi/4 - atan(t))^2 * log(t) / (1-t^2) ))
    %89 = -0.357038604620289042902893412499686912781214141574556097366337
    ? intnum( t=0, 1, (pi/4 - atan(t))^2 * log(t) / (1-t^2) )
    %90 = -0.357038604620289042902893412499686912781214141574556097366337
  ```

In words:
$$
\begin{aligned}
K
&=
\int_0^1\arctan^2 t\cdot\log t\;\frac{2}{1-t^2}\; dt
\\
&=
\Re
\int_0^i\left(\frac \pi 4-\arctan t\right)^2 \cdot\log t\;\frac 1{1-t^2}\; dt
\\
&=
\int_0^1\left(\frac \pi 4-\arctan t\right)^2 \cdot\log t\;\frac 1{1-t^2}\; dt
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Note the integration margins. What happens if we take the integral on $[0,i]$ instead of $[0,1]$ in the $K$-integral? Numerically:

```
    ? 2 * real(intnum( t=0, i, atan(t)^2 * log(t) / (1-t^2) ))
    %98 = 1.52201704740628808181938019826101736327699352613570971392919
    ? pi^4/64
    %99 = 1.52201704740628808181938019826101736327699352613570971392919
```

In words:
$$
\begin{aligned}
K^*
&:=
\Re\int_0^i\arctan^2 t\cdot\log t\;\frac{2}{1-t^2}\; dt
\\
&=\frac 1{64}\pi^4
\\
&=
-\int_0^1\left(\frac \pi 4+\arctan t\right)^2 \cdot\log t\;\frac 1{1-t^2}\; dt
\\
&=-J\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

(These observations were leading to the formula for $K$ in *loc. cit.* .)

- One idea is to use partial integration in $J$ or $K$. Well, we have for $K$:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  K 
  &=
  \int_0^1\arctan^2 t\cdot\log t\;\left(-\log\frac {1-t}{1+t}\right)'\; dt
  \\
  &=
  \underbrace{\int_0^1\arctan^2 t\cdot\frac 1t\cdot \log\frac {1-t}{1+t}\; dt}_{=2K\text{ (why?)}}
  \\
  &\qquad\qquad+
  \underbrace{
  \int_0^1
  2\arctan t\cdot\frac 1{1+t^2}\cdot \log t\cdot \log\frac {1-t}{1+t}\; dt
  }_{=-K\text{ (why?)}}
  \ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- Note that $\arctan$ is related to the logarithm (over $\Bbb C$), we have the relation
  (around $0$)
  $$
  \arctan t=\frac 1{2i}\log\frac {1+it}{1-it}\ .
  $$
  The substitution $t=\frac{1-u}{1+u}$ and the formula for $\tan(\arctan 1-\arctan u)$ are giving:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  K 
  &=
  \int_0^1\arctan^2 t\cdot\log t\;\frac{2}{1-t^2}\; dt
  \\
  &=\int_0^1
  \left(\frac\pi2-\arctan u\right)^2\cdot\log\frac {1-u}{1+u}\cdot \frac {du}u\ .
  \\
  &=\int_1^\infty
  \left(\frac\pi2-\arctan u\right)^2\cdot\log\frac {u-1}{1+u}\cdot \frac {du}u\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  (Write $\log t=\frac 12\log t^2$ to have the same expression under the integral on $(0,1)$ and on $(1,\infty)$.)
- Note the fact that the factor $\frac 2{1-t^2}$ is not "random". It is the right one to make things feasible. It is the derivative of $\displaystyle -\log\frac{1-t}{1+t}$, and plugging in $t=iu$ into $\displaystyle \log\frac{1-t}{1+t}$ leads to an expression related to $\arctan u$. And conversely, $\arctan(iu)$ is related to such a logarithmic expression in $u$.

Comment: When certain products of $\arctan, \log$ yield an integral with simple answer, there need not be an immediate explanation for its simplicity. For example, [easier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050696), [harder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953815), [harder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290482). Nevertheless, there is a systematic and algorithmic way to establish such integral, look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243) for details.

Comment: $$\underbrace{\int_0^12\arctan^2 t\cdot\frac 1{t+t^2}\cdot \log t\cdot \log\frac {1-t}{1+t}\; dt}_{=-K\text{ (why?)}}$$ is not correct
$$\underbrace{\int_0^12\arctan t\cdot\frac 1{1+t^2}\cdot \log t\cdot \log\frac {1-t}{1+t}\; dt}_{=-K\text{ (why?)}}$$

Comment: @user178256 Yes, thanks for pointing to the error!

Answer (score 6):

**A Mind-blowing Solution by Cornel Ioan Valean**

**It is this way!** Again, it is one of those integrals where it is **incredibly difficult** to imagine that a simple solution is possible. And yet, it is possible such a simple solution!

First, let the variable change $\displaystyle t\mapsto \frac{1-t}{1+t}$ in the main integral that becomes
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\arctan(t)\right)^2\frac{\log(t)}{1-t^2}\textrm{d}t=\underbrace{-\int_0^1 \frac{\displaystyle\left(\pi/2-\arctan(t)\right)^2 \operatorname{arctanh}(t)}{t}\textrm{d}t}_{\displaystyle I}.$$

Now, the **magical step** is to consider the following result $\displaystyle\frac{(\pi/2-\arctan(t))^2}{t}=2\int_0^1 \frac{x\operatorname{arctanh}(x)}{t(t^2+x^2)}\textrm{d}x$ exploited in **Cornel**'s answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4407406), and then we have that
$$\small I=-2\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1\frac{x\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(t)}{t(t^2+x^2)}\textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}t=-2\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1\frac{x\operatorname{arctanh}(x)\operatorname{arctanh}(t)}{t(t^2+x^2)}\textrm{d}t\right)\textrm{d}x$$
$$=-2\left(\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(t)}{t}\textrm{d}t}_{\displaystyle \pi^2/8}\right)^2+\underbrace{2\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1\frac{t\operatorname{arctanh}(t)\operatorname{arctanh}(x)}{x(x^2+t^2)}\textrm{d}t\right)\textrm{d}x}_{\displaystyle -I},$$

whence, **by symmetry reasons**, we obtain the desired result
$$\color{blue}{I=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\arctan (t)\right)^2\frac{\log(t)}{1-t^2}\textrm{d}t=-\frac{\pi^4}{64}.}$$

**End of story**

Many such *powerful auxiliary tools*  will be presented in the sequel of **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.

**A simple generalization of the main double integral**

Based on the symmetry ideas above, there is room for generalizations of the type $$\color{red}{\int_a^b \left(\int_a^b\frac{x f(x)f(y)}{y(y^2+x^2)}\textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}y=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x\right)^2},$$
which may be a very strong result for deriving more difficult integrals.

**A STUNNING GENERALIZATION** (with the $n$th power of the inverse hyperbolic tangent)
$$\color{purple}{\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{arctanh}^n(x)}{x}\Re\biggr\{\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}+i\frac{2 x}{1+x^2}\right)\biggr \}\textrm{d}x}$$
$$\color{purple}{=2^{-3 n-1} \left(2^{n+1}-1\right)n!\zeta^2(n+1)},$$
where it is used $\color{red}{\text{the generalization in red}}$ and the generalization at the point $i)$ in **Cornel**'s post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4310997) - more similar results may be obtained with other of those generalizations, and some of them will appear in the sequel of **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.

Comment: Unique as always (+1)

Answer (score 2):

*This not an answer*

Considering that
$$\big[\tan ^{-1}(t)\big]^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,a_n\,t^{2n}$$ where
$$a_n=\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 {2k-1}=\frac{H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}+2 \log (2)}{2 n}$$and using the fact that
$$\int_0^1\frac {t^{2n}}{1-t^2}\log(t)=-\frac{1}{4} \zeta \left(2,\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)$$
$$K=2\int_0^1\big[\tan ^{-1}(t)\big]^2\,\frac{\log (t)}{1-t^2}\,dt$$
$$K=\frac 14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\zeta \left(2,n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}+2 \log
   (2)\right)}{n}$$ which converges extremely slowly.