# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ H_{n/2}}{(2n+1)^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

How to prove that

> $$S=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ H_{n/2}}{(2n+1)^3} \quad=\quad \frac{\pi^2G}{4}-\frac{21\zeta(3)\ln(2)}{8}+\frac{\pi^4}{64}+\frac{\Psi^{(3)}(\frac{1}{4})}{512}- \frac{\Psi^{(3)}(\frac{3}{4})}
> {512}$$

This problem was proposed by @Ahmad Bow but unfortunately it was closed as off-topic and you can find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384512/the-closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-h-fracn22n13).

---

Any way, I tried hard on this one but no success yet. here is what I did:

Using the identity

$$H_{n/2}=H_n-n\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln(1+x)\ dx, \quad x\mapsto x^2$$

$$H_{n/2}=H_n-2n\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\ln(1+x^2)\ dx$$

We can write

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^3}-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)^3}\ dx$$

where

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)^3}&=\frac1x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}-\frac1x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&=\frac1{2x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}(1+(-1)^n-\frac1{2x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}(1+(-1)^n\\
&=\frac1{2x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n^2}(1-(-1)^n-\frac1{2x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n^3}(1-(-1)^n\\
&=\frac1{2x}\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)\right)
\end{align}

Therefore

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^3}-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2}\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)\right)\ dx$$

The sum can be done using [the following identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540515)

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{ (n+a)^{2}}= \left(\gamma + \psi(a) \right) \psi_{1}(a) - \frac{\psi_{2}(a)}{2} \, , \quad a >0.$$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $a$ then set $a=1/2$ we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac{45}{32}\zeta(4)-\frac74\ln2\zeta(3)$$

---

and the question here is how to calculate the the remaining integral or a different way to tackle the sum $S$ ? Thanks

---

Comment: Please give the reference to this closed question.

Comment: Sure .. I will edit now

Comment: This is a nice question (+1), but please, don't use the question body as a place to vent your frustration against close-voters of another question. If you want to contest a closed question, voting to reopen and/or posting on meta is the right thing to do here. Being sarcastic is not going to help you.

Comment: I did vote to reopen but 5 votes are required to reooen a closed question and there was only two votes to reopen so the problem got closed. Voting to close problem with no reasonable reason is really irritating to me . one of my nice questions got closed too.

Comment: @JeanMarie The question is in the linked question list ... Ahmad Bow ! not Ahmed.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit thanks.. edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cornel**'s way to make it easy. Replace the harmonic number in the numerator by Digamma function, using that $H_{n/2}= \psi(n/2+1)+\gamma$, and then splitting the series using the parity, we have

$$ S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \psi(n/2+1)+\gamma}{(2n+1)^3}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \psi(n+1)+\gamma}{(4n+1)^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \psi(n+1/2)+\gamma}{(4n-1)^3}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{(4n+1)^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ 2H_{2n}-H_n-2\log(2)}{(4n-1)^3}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{(4n+1)^3}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{(4n-1)^3}-2\log(2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4n-1)^3}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n}}{(4n-1)^3},$$
and since the first two series are straightforward using **Cornel**'s *Master Theorem of Series* from [A master theorem of series and an evaluation of a cubic harmonic series](http://jca.ele-math.com/10-10/A-master-theorem-of-series-and-an-evaluation-of-a-cubic-harmonic-series), which is also given in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, and then noting that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n}}{(4n-1)^3}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{(2n-1)^3}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_{n}}{(2n-1)^3}\right),$$

where for the first series we can use the same mentioned master theorem, and then the second one is already known in the form  $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_{n}}{(2n+1)^3}$ (it's easy to rearrange the series according to our needs), and you may find its value [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1757944494302341&set=pb.100002604219021.-2207520000.1571092338.&type=3&theater) together with a solution in comments, we're done.

End of story.

Comment: impressive (+1).. but splitting the series is kinda unclear to me.

Comment: Above we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(2n-1)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(2n)$. Then, $\displaystyle \psi(n+1/2)$ is well known.

Comment: All clear.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the identity  ( I can provide the proof if wanted but it's a nice problem to try)

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2\right)\cos(x(2n+1))=\frac{x}{2\sin x}$$

Multiply both sides by $x^2$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $\pi/2$ to get

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x^3}{2\sin x}\ dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2\right)\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\cos(x(2n+1))\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2\right)\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}\frac{\cos(nx)}{2n+1}-\frac{2\cos(nx)}{(2n+1)^3}-\frac{\pi\sin(nx)}{(2n+1)^2}\right)
\end{align}

Note that  inside the sum, $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(nx)$ behave as $(-1)^{n}$ and $0$ respectively, then

$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2}{2n+1}-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n/2}}{(2n+1)^3}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{(2n+1)^3}-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\ln2}{(2n+1)^3}$$

rearrange

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n/2}}{(2n+1)^3}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{(2n+1)^3}-\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\ln2}{(2n+1)^3}}_{\frac78\ln2\zeta(3)}+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2}{2n+1}}_{M}-\frac12I$$

---

From the question body, we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac{45}{32}\zeta(4)-\frac74\ln2\zeta(3)$$

---

To calculate $M$, we use the identity

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1+x}\ dx=H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2$$

\begin{align}
M&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{2n+1}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)}\ dx\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\tanh^{-1}x}{1+x^2}\ dx=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x^2}\ dx=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\ dx=G
\end{align}

.

---

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x^3}{2\sin x}\ dx\overset{IBP}{=}-\frac32\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 \ln(\tan(x/2))\ dx\\
&=3\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 \cos(x(2n+1))\ dx\\
&=3\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}-\frac{2(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}\right)\\
&=\frac{3\pi^2}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}-6\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^4}\\
&=\frac{3\pi^2}{4}G-6\beta(4)
\end{align}

where [$\beta(4)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function?fbclid=IwAR2JKUjyn8sG4wMdUfeT3JyJLpw7C-aanbnwRYbIZ0k9QYwA3Hz1_0OsQhU) $=\frac1{768}\psi_3(1/4)-\frac{\pi^4}{96}$

By combining these results we get the desired closed form.

Comment: magical solution (+1).

Answer (score 2):

I asked **Cornel** for a solution to the nice key result from Ahmad Bow's solution. Here is a solution in large steps.
We need two known results, that is $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1+x}\textrm{d}x=H_{n/2}-H_n+\log(2)$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^n \cos(nx)=\frac{p(\cos(x)-p)}{1-2p\cos(x)+p^2}, \ |p|<1$. If replacing $p$ by $i \sqrt{p}$ in the last series, make rearrangements and reindexing the series, we obtain$\displaystyle \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n y^n \cos ((2 n+1) x)=\frac{(1+y) \cos (x)}{1+2y \cos (2 x)+y^2}$.

Then, we have 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2\right)\cos((2n+1)x)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+y}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n y^n\cos((2n+1)x)\textrm{d}y
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\cos (x)\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+2y \cos (2 x)+y^2}\textrm{d}y=\cos (x)\int_{\cos(2x)}^{1+\cos(2x)} \frac{1}{t^2+\sin^2(2x)}\textrm{d}t=\frac{x}{2\sin(x)}.
\end{equation*}

End of story.

Comment: nice proof.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another proof besides Cornel's one:

Let

\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2)e^{ix(2n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^1\frac{y^n \ dy}{1+y}e^{ix(2n+1)}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{e^{ix}\ dy}{1+y}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-ye^{2ix}\right)^n\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{e^{ix}\ dy}{(1+y)(1+e^{2ix}y)}\\
&=\frac{e^{ix}}{1-e^{2ix}}\left(\ln2-\ln(1+e^{2ix})\right)\\
&=\frac{i}{2\sin x}\left(-\ln(\cos x)-ix\right)\\
&=\frac{x}{2\sin x}-i\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{2\sin x}
\end{align}

substituting $e^{ix(2n+1)}=\cos(x(2n+1))+i\sin(x(2n+1))$ and comparing the real and imaginary parts we get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2)\cos(x(2n+1))=\frac{x}{2\sin x}\tag1$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2)\sin(x(2n+1))=-\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{2\sin x}\tag2$$

---

If we follow the same approach, we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2)\cos(x(2n+1))=-\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{2\cos x}\tag3$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(H_{n/2}-H_n+\ln2)\sin(x(2n+1))=\frac{\pi/2-x}{2\cos x}\tag4$$

---

The identity in (1) is discovered by @Ahmad Bow.

Answer (score -1):

Using W.A.as well as my previous calculations on harmonics sums.
 I find $$S=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ H_{n/2}}{(2n+1)^3} \quad=\quad -\frac{\pi^2G}{4}-2G+\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{21\zeta(3)\ln(2)}{8}+\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\frac{\pi^3}{16}+\frac{\pi^4}{64}+\ln2-2-3\beta(4)+\frac{\Psi^{(3)}(\frac{1}{4})}{256}- \frac{\Psi^{(3)}(\frac{3}{4})}
{256}$$
 $$ S=0,047743102114778065267...$$
 But I'm not sure of the result.

Comment: but the result is mentioned in the question body and your result does not match. you got extra terms.